# Debugging a DLL which is in another solution on VS2003

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, dll, debugging, breakpoints

I'm am trying to debug a DLL which is called from a VC++ application,
but cannot step-inside the DLL function because the DLL source is located 
in another solution project.

I have tried to set a break point right before the DLL function call but
when I try to step-in it just passes right down.

I am aware that it is possible to just debug the DLL on its own and feed it 
arguments, but since there are many variables, I do not find it practical
for debugging purposes.

Is there a way to debug a DLL that is separate from the Invoking Application
as if it where a single solution file?

Comment: the dll is created not by solution is created by project part.
the project you can attach to multiply solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing you can do is start up your app outside of VS, open the solution with the DLL, and attach to the application.

Comment: That did it!
Didnt know it was so simple to attach to proccesses
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Build a debug version of the DLL and link to it in the debug configuration of your project. That should get you what you need. It should find the source of the DLL and you should be able to step into it.

Comment: How do you "link to it in the debug configuration of your project?" Thanks!

Comment: If your DLL is named mydll.dll, then you have your dll project create mydll_d.dll in its debug configuration. Then your exe debug configuration links mydll_d.lib instead of mydll.lib (or loads mydll_d.dll instead of mydll.dll if it loads dynamically) and ensure that the mydll_d.pdb is with it.